# Paperclip, S3, Rails—Aws::S3::Errors::InvalidArgument ():

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, paperclip, ruby-on-rails-5

As the title suggests, I'm using paperclip and S3 with Rails. When I try to create a record that has an image, I get this error:

```
[paperclip] saving interactives/5/images/original/Havaneser_Anton.jpg
   (6.6ms)  ROLLBACK
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 2021ms (ActiveRecord: 86.8ms)



Aws::S3::Errors::InvalidArgument ():
```

I don't know what's going on, other than "It's not working"...

Here is my `development.rb` configuration:

```
Rails.application.configure do
  # Settings specified here will take precedence over those in config/application.rb.

  config.paperclip_defaults = {
    storage: :s3,
    s3_permissions: :public,
    s3_region: ENV['AWS_REGION'],
    s3_credentials: {
      access_key_id: ENV['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'],
      secret_access_key: ENV['AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'],
      bucket: ENV['AWS_S3_BUCKET']
    },
    s3_protocol: 'https',
    s3_host_name: "s3-#{ENV['AWS_REGION']}.amazonaws.com",
    path: ":class/:id/:attachment/:style/:filename"
  }
```

My Model looks like this:

```
class Interactive < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :project
  has_attached_file :image, styles: { low_res: "10%", medium: "300x300>", thumb: "300x250>" }, default_url: "/images/:style/missing.png"
  validates_attachment_content_type :image, content_type: /\Aimage\/.*\z/
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your `s3_permissions: :public`, the value for this option should be one of the "Canned ACL" permissions from [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/acl-overview.html#canned-acl). `:public` does not appear to be an option!